# I have problem while install neo4j on REHL 9

Tags: java, neo4j, redhat, rhel

I have problem with jre while installing neo4j

I'm trying to install neo4j following the instructions at https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/rpm/
[I installed openjdk-17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RiNg.png)

But when I run sudo yum install https://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-java17-adapter.noarch.rpm command it shows me this:

[image]

I don't know what happened with my jre.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction to install the java17-adapter are under the Oracle java section because that only needs doing if you use Oracle java.

Why you're installing it on top of OpenJDK17 I don't know.

You already have a compatible jre installed, you can continue installing neo4j as normal.